# DNN production site backup on localhost keeps redirecting to Production URL

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am trying to install a production DNN site on my local computer. For it I hosted the production site on my Windows 7 PC with IIS 7.

I have removed all entries from PortalAlias table except one that points to localhost, but when I browse the URL, it automatically gets redirected to the production URL from where I took the backup.

I have reset the IIS and have also tried restarting my system once :(
Production site is on DNN 7 and has several third party modules on it.

Can someone suggest me what else can I try to get that production site working on my local system?

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config file, if you are using URLMaster from Ifinity you'll find that it may also have a setting in the web.config which controls the domain name.

The other thing to make sure, is that your web.config points to your local database, not the production database.

Comment: Thanks for reply Chris, but this wasn't issue in my case. For me culprit were site settings "DefaultPortalAlias" and "PortalAliasMapping" :)